# jQuery animation gets executed only once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function:

```
  function flipAndFade(elemToAnimate,overlay) {
      elemToAnimate.animate({ textIndent: 0 }, {
          step: function (go) {
              $(this).css('-moz-transform', 'rotateY(' + go + '360deg)');
              $(this).css('-webkit-transform', 'rotateY(' + go + '360deg)');
              $(this).css('-o-transform', 'rotateY(' + go + '360deg)');
              $(this).css('transform', 'rotateY(' + go + '360deg)');

              $(".overlay-bg").delay('600').fadeIn('slow', function () {
                  $(this).stop();
              });
              overlay.delay('600').fadeIn('slow', function () {
                  $(this).stop();
              });

              $(".overlay-bg").animate({ "top": 0 }, { duration: 1 });
              $(".overlay-bg").animate({ "left": 0 }, { duration: 1 });
              overlay.animate({ "top": 0 }, { duration: 1 });
              overlay.animate({ "left": 0 }, { duration: 1 });
          },
          duration: 1000,
          complete: function () {
              $(this).animate().stop();
          }
      });         
  }
```

And i have two elemnts listening for click:

```
$(".module3").click(function(){
    flipAndFade($(".module3"), $(".overlay3"));
});
$(".module4").click(function(){
    flipAndFade($(".module4"), $(".overlay4"));
});
```

But the problem is when i click on the first element all works fine. But then clicking on the second element does not execute the animation. If I refresh and click on the second one, it works, but then the first one it does not. I read in the posts about function queuing, but i am not clear how to do that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: FYI, and this is certainly just personal preference, but it appears you are mixing both CSS animations and jQuery animations. I'd suggest sticking with just CSS animations, an set the logic up in classes in your CSS file. That way, to trigger the animation, you can simply have jQuery add the class that animates to the object. Should make things a little easier to organize.

Answer (score 0):

If there are multiple instances of `.module3` in your page, then you need to do this:

```
$(".module3").click(function(){
    flipAndFade($(this), $(".overlay3"));
});
```

And, only call this once as it will serve all your `.module3` elements with this one block of code.

Or, if there's only one `.module3` and one `.module4`, then you can serve both with this and you really want to pass `$(".module3")` to both, then you can just combine the selectors and use one piece of code like this:

```
$(".module3, module4").click(function(){
    flipAndFade($(".module3"), $(".overlay3"));
});
```

---

If there is a different `.overlay3` for each `.module3`, then you will need to change the code further in order to specify which `.overlay3` goes with which `.module3` probably using `$(this).find(some selector)`, but I'd need to see the HTML that contains `.overlay3` to know exactly what you need.

---

Then, I'd ask why are you calling `$(this).animate().stop();` in the `complete:` handler?  The animation should already be done right?

Comment: I removed $(this).animate().stop(); you are right. Those are different elements, i had a typo, sorry. They have different names but the problems still there...

Answer (score -1):

Seems like the click handlers are for the same selector `$(".module3")`

Comment: @DA does this fiddle look like something you are doing ? Please do edit if not and will be able to help you more http://jsfiddle.net/X8tL4/1/